# CloudKit nil optional error

Tags: arrays, swift, if-statement, option-type, cloudkit

I am trying to load, then modify and resave an array.

Here is code, modify func is the top one:

```
func modifyUserGroupsRequestee(){
    print("step2")
    acceptedUsersArray.append(groupNameLbl.text!)
    //error
    userGroupRecordToUpdate.setObject(acceptedUsersArray as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "userGroups")
    database.save(recordToUpdate) { (savedRecord, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }else{
            print("SAVED RECORD")
        } 
    } 
}

func resaveUserGroups(){
    print(addedUser)
    print("step1")
    // add group to requestees user groups
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", "\(addedUser)")
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "PersonalUser", predicate: pred)
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)  
    //operation.resultsLimit = CKQueryOperationMaximumResults
    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) in
        if record != nil{
            self.userGroupRecordToUpdate = record
           // self.acceptedUsersArray = (record.object(forKey: "userGroups") as! Array)
            print("usergroup names:: \(self.acceptedUsersArray)")
            if let acceptedUserArrays = record.object(forKey: "userGroups") as? [String] {
               // self.feedTableView.reloadData()
                self.acceptedUsersArray = acceptedUserArrays
                print("looks like we r going forward")
                self.modifyUserGroupsRequestee() 
          //  }
            //self.feedTableView.reloadData()
            print(groupNames.count)
            print(self.acceptedUsersArray)
        }   
    }
    database.add(operation)
    //self.tableView.reloadData()
    // print(leaderboardInfo.count)
   }
}
```

The function prints step1 but never gets to step2. In the bottom function, I have an if let statement I tried to create to solve my nil issue (I commented my previous code above that line- self.acceptedUsersArray...  Anyway, I believe I am implementing the if let statement incorrectly, because no data is loaded, even though there is data in cloud kit.

And I do have my personal user cloudKit records set up, here's a pic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try to keep your code always indented consistently.
(In Xcode editor, Cmd+A (Select All), then Ctrl+I (Re-Indent).)

With confusing comments removed, your `resaveUserGroups` shows as:

```
func resaveUserGroups() {
    print(addedUser)
    print("step1")
    // add group to requestees user groups
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", "\(addedUser)")

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "PersonalUser", predicate: pred)

    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) in

        if record != nil {
            self.userGroupRecordToUpdate = record
            print("usergroup names:: \(self.acceptedUsersArray)")

            if let acceptedUserArrays = record.object(forKey: "userGroups") as? [String] {
                self.acceptedUsersArray = acceptedUserArrays
                print("looks like we r going forward")
                self.modifyUserGroupsRequestee()

                print(groupNames.count)
                print(self.acceptedUsersArray)
            }
        }
        database.add(operation)
    }
}
```

Omitting some parts to clarify:

```
func resaveUserGroups() {
    //...

    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) in

        if record != nil {
            //...
        }
        database.add(operation)
    }
}
```

The line `database.add(operation)` exists inside the `recordFetchedBlock`.

You may need to fix some more parts (that's another story), but at least, you need to move the line out of the closure to execute the `operation` you have created:

```
func resaveUserGroups() {
    //...

    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) in

        if record != nil {
            //...
        }
        //database.add(operation) 
    }   //↓
    database.add(operation)
}
```

Comment: I moved the one operation line but it didn't change the fact that the code inside the if let statement isn't called even though it should be cause its not nil.

Comment: What do you get if you put `print(record)` just before the if-let?

Comment: I need to post this code snippet separately cause its too big... Optional(<CKRecord: 0x100d42360; recordID=3F9D16E4-7A4F-EDF5-8628-841322D91510:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=j6b336u7, values={
    email = r;
    fullName = jacob;
    password = jaj;
    username = jacobbbb;
}, recordType=PersonalUser>
{

Comment: Second Part...     
 READ-ONLY
 creatorUserRecordID -> <CKRecordID: 0x17003e000; recordName=_d08a474b97187e0ae34d7609845686d6, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
 lastModifiedUserRecordID -> <CKRecordID: 0x17003cb20; recordName=_d08a474b97187e0ae34d7609845686d6, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
 creationDate -> 2017-08-13 18:48:47 +0000
 modificationDate -> 2017-08-13 18:51:50 +0000
 modifiedByDevice -> 2
 email -> "r"
 password -> "jaj"
 username -> "jacobbbb"
 fullName -> "jacob"
})

Comment: You can include such info with editing your question. But I cannot find any `userGroups` in the output. What do you get when you put `print(record.object(forKey: "userGroups"))` ?

Comment: It returns "nil"

Comment: Seems you have not setup your `PersonalUser` to include a field named `userGroups`. You are not showing anything about how have you setup `PersonalUser`, so I cannot say any more.

Comment: I do have it setup, I just uploaded a pic to my question as proof. This is why I'm confused.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, but this is not in the cases I have ever encountered. Hope someone who can solve this issue finds this thread soon.

Comment: One last thing...I am adding the code where I set off the function (should be up in a min). Please have one last look :)

Comment: Seems you have edited my answer, but that sort of info should be included in your question. Please update your question. I surely watch it and when I can find which can be helpful, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it. Apparently there always needs to be some kind of value inside the array even if it was just created. I was trying to query an array that existed in the recordType, but not yet under the specific record.